# Queue linked list front method

Tags: java, queue

Can the return statement not be inside the `if` statement?
When I compile, I get this error:

> QueueTestList.java:180: error: missing return statement.

My code:

```
public coordinate front() 
{
    if(!empty())
    {
    queueNode firstNode = last.getNext();
        return firstNode.getCoord();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that if `empty()` returns `true`, the method does not have a value to return. The method needs to return a value (or throw an exception) in all cases.

```
public coordinate front() 
{
    if (empty())
        return null;

    queueNode firstNode = last.getNext();
    return firstNode.getCoord();
}
```

On a side note, classes should start with a capital letter (`Coordinate`).